# Django database models - messages and recipients: many-to-many or many-to-one?

Tags: mysql, django, database, django-models

I am using MySQL for my database and have the following `Message` model in my Django app:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='sender_notification')
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='recipient_notification')
    message = models.TextField()
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    recieved_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

If I am not mistaken, this way the relationship between `recipient`/`User` and `Message` is **one-to-many**, since a single `Message` record can only have one `recipient`, but a `User` might have many records in the `Message` table. However, there will be situations where I want to send the same `Message` to multiple `Users`. With my current schema, I can just add multiple `Message` records, one for each recipient, with the same `message` text. However, this seems like a lot of duplication. In this case, would my relationship make more sense as a many-to-many one?

Initially I thought the duplication (multiple `Messages` with the same `message` field but different `recipient` fields) was a bad idea, but the more I think about it, it seems like modeling the many-to-many relationship would actually be more difficult, and require more data. Each `Message` record has a `read` field to indicate whether the recipient has read the message or not. If I have a single `Message` record with multiple `recipients` then it seems like I will need another table to keep track of the recipients who have and have not read the message. This means that if I want to send a message to every user, I will need to add one row to the  `Message` table, but will have to add one row to a "read record" table for each recipient. So not only am I creating more rows total (1 `Message`, and one read record each for n users, as opposed to n `Message`s for n users), I am also adding an additional table to the mix.

I have done many searches trying to determine whether it is better to have a single table with many rows, or multiple tables with fewer rows, and it seems like there is no definitive answer; instead, it depends on your data and requirements. I am just looking for some insight into the best direction to go in my particular case, but am also interested in any general rules that I might be able to follow in the future, if such rules exist for this kind of situation.

I am very open to having more work for myself up front in order to do things the "right" way (if there is such a thing in this case), if that happens to be necessary. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

A way of solving the issue with the "read" flag for multiple users is to use a many-to-many with a custom through model, and put that flag there:

```
class UserMessage(models.Model):
    read = models.BooleanField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User...)
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message...)

class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, through=UserMessage)
```

Now each user has an individual "read" field for each message, no matter how many users also read that message. Given the user and the message, you can get the intermediate model with `UserMessage.objects.get(user=user, message=message)`.

Comment: Very interesting. This is a very useful pattern that I was not aware of! However, I am still curious, if I have a message to send to 10 users, is there an advantage to creating a single `Message` and 10 `UserMessage`s, compared to using the example model in my question and creating 10 `Message`s, each with a different `recipient`? One disadvantage I have experienced with my current method is that I cannot send a message to multiple users at once through the default admin interface (because I can only select a single `recipient`), but this is a disadvantage I can live with. Are there others?

Comment: I am trying this approach now and will accept this answer once I have confirmed that it works for me. But please update your code example a little bit: `Message` needs to be defined first to avoid raising a `NameError` for the `message` field on `UserMessage` which references `Message`, and the `through` argument needs to be a string (again, to avoid raising a `NameError`). Thank you!